# How to get user's IP address while accessing a website in drupal 8

Tags: get, ip, drupal-8

How to get user's IP address while accessing a website in drupal 8?

I tried "Request()->getClientIp()" but it's not returning the "X-Forwarded-For" IP.

I tried the following but getting the host name(127.0.0.1) only.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  print '<pre>';
  echo 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP =';
  echo $ip;exit(); 
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  print '<pre>';
  echo 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR =';echo $ip;exit();
} else {
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  print '<pre>';
  echo 'REMOTE_ADDR =';
  echo $ip;exit();
}
```

I tried following "https://campus.barracuda.com/product/webapplicationfirewall/doc/4259905/logging-actual-client-ip-address-on-the-apache-server/" but still not getting the user's IP.

Please guide me with respect to Drupal 8

Comment: you can format code by placing 4 spaces in front of a line. Alternately you can click the code button. This will help with the readability of your post.

Comment: Take a look at the answer on the following page https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214003/how-to-get-ip-address